# ASP.NET BlogEngine.NET HTTP 403 Error (Admin Pages Only)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis-7.5, blogengine.net

I recently installed the latest version of BlogEngine.NET (v3.0).  The blog itself renders fine on my browser (i.e., viewing the main page, individual blog posts, etc.) However, when I log in and try to access any of the Admin pages (i.e., Settings, Users, etc.), I am getting an HTTP 403 (Forbidden) error.

This is happening on both Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 as well as Windows Server 2012 x64.  When I installed a local copy on my Windows 8.1 Pro machine, it works fine.

I know the admin pages all render in MVC-style, since the URL is "/admin/#/settings", for Settings for example.

I have literally tried everything. I verified that the application pool identity has Write permissions to the entire web site folder structure.

Any thoughts/ideas?  I am completely stuck and would appreciate any guidance.  Thanks in advance.

*** UPDATE ***

Some progress- I tried creating a standalone website in IIS just for BlogEngine.NET, i.e., http://www.example.com instead of http://www.example.com/blog, and it worked flawlessly.

Therefore, something is going screwy with the permissions when I am creating an Application within the main Website (i.e., www.example.com/blog).

Thoughts?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Having same issue. But we are routing it in staging as mainsite.com/staging/blog instead of staging.mainsite.com/blog.

Comment: It appears the /admin 403 issue still exists in 2018. As anyone solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ancient post, but adding these `<appSettings>` helped for me:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" /> 
</appSettings>
```

Alternatively, you can start the section by getting rid of all inherited values:

```
<appSettings>
    <clear />
    <!-- Other settings here -->
</appSettings>
```

In my main site I explicitly had a setting `<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />`, so that explains why it was necessary to add this.

You also need to do this for other sections, like `<connectionStrings>`.